# Rename multi-frame dicom images

Tags: matlab, rename, dicom

I have a dicom file that contains 110 images and their names are random. I am trying to rename them according to their SliceLocations (`n`) and rewrite them with the dcm extension, i.e., n(1).dcm, n(2).dcm, …

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

I tried

```
image_list=dir('*.dcm');
for i=1:110
img=dicomread(image_list);
imgHdr = dicominfo(image_list(i).name);
  for j = size(img,4);
    dicomwrite(img(:,:,:,j),['n(' int2str(j) ').dcm'],imgHdr,'CreateMode','Copy');

  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Slice location (0020,1041) is an optional attribute for image plane module. There is no guarantee that tag will have any value. Your best option is to use the Image Position (Patient) (0020, 0032) attribute. This will have x, y, and z coordinates of the upper left hand corner (center of the first voxel transmitted) of the image. See [DICOM standard PS 3.3 - 2011](http://medical.nema.org/Dicom/2011/11_03pu.pdf) (PDF), Annex C.7.6.2.1, for further explanation.

Comment: Thanks @LEADtools Support, what if I want to rename them according to their depths ?

Comment: Only one value (axial) in the Image Position (Patient) attribute will change between the slices (parallel slices). You can use that value to calculate slice position/location.  Each image frame Image Position (Patient) specifies the origin of the image with respect to the patient-based coordinate system where the x-axis is increasing to the left hand side of the patient. The y-axis is increasing to the posterior side of the patient. The z-axis is increasing toward the head of the patient. This  should work for CT stack but in case of MR, you may find single series with multiple stacks.

Answer (score 1):

**NOTE:** *This answer applies to "frames," not "slices." The two are apparently different things for DICOM files.*

One convenient option, if you don't need exactly the naming scheme in your question, is to use the `'MultiframeSingleFile'` option in the [`dicomwrite`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/dicomwrite.html) function:

```
X = dicomread('MultiFrameFile.dcm');
dicomwrite(X,'n.dcm','MultiframeSingleFile',false);
```

This will produce files named `'n_01.dcm'`, `'n_02.dcm'`, ...

Otherwise you can use a simple `for` loop in conjunction with [`int2str`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/int2str.html):

```
X = dicomread('MultiFrameFile.dcm');
for i = size(X,4);
    dicomwrite(X(:,:,:,i),['n(' int2str(i) ').dcm']);
end
```

Comment: Thanks @horchler for your help. Sorry I didn't make that clear, I have 110 dicoms (slices), so I am trying to rename them according to their depth location (slice location). I tried what your way and modified a bit (updated the question), but the output only one dcm.